# What is the meaning of integrating by parts of the generating functional?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, path-integral, mathematics

Let
$
\varphi^{i}(x) \equiv \varphi^{A}
$
be boson fields and let
$$
S_{0}=S_{0}(\varphi)=\int d x L\left(\varphi^{i}(x), \partial_{\mu} \varphi^{i}(x)\right)
$$
be a classical action.

Consider the family of classical actions $S(\alpha, \varphi)$:
$$
S(\alpha, \varphi)=S_{0}(\Phi(\alpha, \varphi))
$$
where the change of variables $\Phi^{A}(\alpha, \varphi)=\Phi^{i}(\alpha, \varphi ; x)=\Phi^{i}\left(\alpha, \varphi^{j}(x), \partial_{\mu} \varphi^{j}(x)\right)$.

Then we have $$
\frac{\partial S(\alpha, \varphi)}{\partial \alpha}-f^{A}(\alpha, \varphi) \frac{\delta S(\alpha, \varphi)}{\delta \varphi^{A}}=0 \tag 2
$$

where $$
f^{A}=f^{A}(\alpha, \varphi)=\frac{\partial \Phi^{B}(\alpha, \varphi)}{\partial \alpha} \frac{\partial \varphi^{A}(\alpha, \Phi)}{\delta \Phi^{B}}, \quad \varphi^{A}(\alpha, \Phi(\alpha, \varphi))=\varphi^{A}.
$$
Given the family of green function generating functionals $Z(\alpha, J):$
$$
\begin{gathered}
Z(\alpha, J)=e^{i W(\alpha, J)}=\int D \varphi \Delta(\alpha, \varphi) e^{i\left(S(\alpha, \varphi)+J_{A} \varphi^{A}\right)} \\
\Delta(\alpha, \varphi)=\operatorname{Det} \frac{\delta \Phi^{A}(\alpha, \varphi)}{\delta \varphi^{B}}.
\end{gathered}
$$

In  this paper [Once again on the equivalence theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0001050) the author says on p. 3 that

> Evaluating the mean of symmetry equation (2) and formally integrating by parts, we obtain the equation for the Green function generating functionals:
> $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} W(\alpha, J)+J^{A}\left\langle f^{A}\right\rangle(\alpha, J)=0 \tag 3
> $$
> where
> $$
> \left\langle f^{A}\right\rangle(\alpha, J) \equiv \frac{1}{{Z}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})} \int D \varphi f^{A}(\alpha, \varphi) \Delta(\alpha, \varphi) e^{i\left(S(\alpha, \varphi)+J_{A} \varphi^{A}\right).}
> $$

My question is what the author means by integrating by parts of the generating functional and what does he means by mean of symmetry of equation $(2)$?

Comment: Do you mean how did the author perform the integration by parts?

Comment: yes that  is one of my question?